# Javascript : Return .innerHTML as syntax

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little problem here...

This is my code

```
<html>
 <textarea id="text">
  <h2>Text Here...</h2>
 </textarea>

 <div id="preview">

 </div>
</html>

<script>
  var syntax = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = syntax;
</script>
```

The problem is the `preview` shows `<h2>Text Here...</h2>` instead of `Text Here...` with `h2` font.

Thanks

Beginner Programmer

Comment: Use `textContent` instead.

Comment: with this code, preview actually shows `[object HTMLDivElement]`

Comment: Look at Azeez anwser. I have to retrive innerHtml from sintax.

Comment: @JaromandaX That's what happens with objects, heh (except functions (instanceof, though))

Comment: @FREEZE - I know why it was that text, my point was that the question stated the displayed text in preview was completely different to that - clearly the code in the question is **not** exactly the code the OP was having issues with

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your script :

```js
  var syntax = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = syntax;
```

```html
 <div id="text">
  <h2>Text Here...</h2>
 </div>

 <div id="preview">

 </div>
```

Comment: It was a 'div' in your question

Comment: I know, i have changed it

Comment: Then you need to change your code also: Please use this line: var syntax = document.getElementById("text").value;

Comment: Use .value instead of .innerHTML and try